# In Subversion, get full URL of branch for most recent change

Tags: batch-file, svn

Briefly - is there a simple svn command to tell us the "*most recently changed branch*"?

In more depth, as part of our build process, we're trying to detect the most recently-changed branch in Subversion, in order to perform further processing on that branch.

For example, if someone added the file:

http://server/svn/project/branches/Integration1/newfile.txt

we'd want to be able to determine the string:

http://server/svn/project/branches/Integration1

that is, the parent folder of the most recent change.

The closest we can find is to execute the following command:

```
svn log --verbose --limit 1 http://server/svn/project/
```

but it then gives a 4-line output that we'd need to parse, using batch.

We have a Jenkins build server with the Subversion plugin installed, which can detect the change to the overall subversion repository, but it only gives us the environment variables SVN_URL and SVN_REVISION, neither of which address our goal.

Comment: A single commit can span a lot of files at different places, so how do you want to deal with that?

Comment: Agreed, there could be many changes, but they'd all be within the same branch.   We just want the full path of the branch that changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will work in your Jenkins environment, but here is what I would do in a standard (eg `bash`) shell. I use a terse `svn log`:

```
svn log ^/branches -l1 -q --incremental
```

Adding a pipe to parse it, the full command would be:

```
svn log ^/branches -l1 -q --incremental | sed -n "s/.*| \(.*\) |.*/\1/p"
```

Replace the caret (`^`) with `http://server/svn/project/`.

**EDIT**: to get the branch name, increase the verbosity of `svn log` with `-v` to print the modified paths, and adapt the `sed` command to extract the branch name. The following works for me:

```
svn log ^/branches -l1 -q -v | sed -n '4 s|.*/branches/||p'
```

or more aggressive:

```
svn log ^/branches -l1 -q -v | sed -nr '4 s|.*/branches/([^/]+).*|\1|p'
```

Comment: Without the --verbose option, that command still just tells me that  _a_ change was made by a user at a certain time - there's no further information about the actual branch that changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```cmd
svn log --verbose --quiet --limit 1 "http://server/svn/project/"
```

So you get rid of any commit log messages and have just a list of modified paths and a header. Then use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to capture the paths:

```cmd
rem // Capture output of `svn log`, skip header and hyphen-only lines:
for /F "skip=3 eol=- tokens=1*" %%I in ('
    svn log --verbose --quiet --limit 1 "http://server/svn/project/"
') do echo(%%J
```

The tricky part is to derive the common root path of multiple items, which might be done like in the following script, for instance (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks in the code; provide the repository path `http://server/svn/project/` as the first command line argument):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_REPOPATH=%~1" & rem // (take the first argument as the repository path)

rem // Clear buffer for common root path:
set "COMM="
rem // Clear all variables beginning with `$`:
for /F "delims=" %%K in ('set $ 2^> nul') do set "%%K="
rem // Capture output of `svn log`, skip header and hyphen-only lines:
for /F "skip=3 eol=- tokens=1*" %%I in ('
    svn log --verbose --quiet --limit 1 "%_REPOPATH%"
') do (
    rem // Store currently iterated path:
    set "ITEM=%%J"
    rem // Check whether buffer for common root path is empty:
    if not defined COMM (
        rem // Buffer is empty, hence this is the first iteration:
        set "COMM=%%J"
    ) else (
        rem // Otherwise, store each `/`-separated path element in array `$ITEM[]`:
        set /A "IDX=0"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%K in ("!ITEM:/=" "!") do (
            for %%L in (!IDX!) do (
                endlocal
                set "$ITEM[%%L]=%%~K"
                set /A "IDX+=1"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        endlocal
        rem // Store each element of buffered common root path in array `$COMM[]`:
        set /A "CNT=IDX-1, IDX=0"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%K in ("!COMM:/=" "!") do (
            for %%L in (!IDX!) do (
                endlocal
                set "$COMM[%%L]=%%~K"
                set /A "IDX+=1"
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            )
        )
        rem // Determine the lower number of elements of `$ITEM[]` and `$COMM[]`:
        if !CNT! geq !IDX! set /A "CNT=IDX-1"
        rem // Loop through both arrays and write all common elements to buffer:
        set "COMM=" & set "FLAG=#"
        for /L %%L in (0,1,!CNT!) do (
            if /I "!$ITEM[%%L]!" == "!$COMM[%%L]!" (
                rem // The flag is just necessary to stop at the first difference:
                if defined FLAG set "COMM=!COMM!!$COMM[%%L]!/"
            ) else set "FLAG="
        )
        rem // Transport the built common root path buffer beyond `endlocal`:
        for /F "delims=" %%K in (""!COMM!"") do (
            endlocal & set "COMM=%%~K"
        )
    )
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined COMM (
    rem // Check if there was only one path and just get get its parent in case:
    if not "!COMM:~-1!" == "/" (
        for %%K in ("!COMM:/=\!") do (
            endlocal & set "COMM=%%~pK"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "COMM=!COMM:\=/!"
        )
    )
    rem // Return the finally retrieved common root path of all paths:
    echo(!COMM:~1,-1!
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```